# Parsing Nested XML with common column names using pandas read_xml

Tags: pandas, xml, dataframe, xml-parsing

I have a nested xml file with common column name (In this case - Name). I need to parse this XML to have different columns.

```
  <Employee>
    <Name>Tanmay</Name>
    <City>
      <Name>ABC</Name>
      <County>
        <Name>Sunny</Name>
      </County>
    </City>
  </Employee>
</Company>
```

When I parse this XML file using

```
df=pd.read_xml("your_xml_file.xml")
print(df)
```

I get

```
   Name  City
  Tanmay   NaN
```

I see an option within pandas read_xml with names. I was wondering if I can use that option for my use case and how do I use it?

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html

```
nameslist-like, optional
Column names for DataFrame of parsed XML data. Use this parameter to rename original element names and distinguish same named elements and attributes.
```

Comment: Please read the `Notes` section on the [URL you provided](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html). You may need to use xslt style sheets to redesign xml doc. Another option is to get values using lxml and xpath and populate df